# 16.04 Software Centre not opening

Tags: unity, software-center, launcher, 16.04

I can open it from the terminal by typing `software-center` but the icon in the launcher does not do anything. I was wondering if someone knows how to fix it? It is a minor irritation however as I've only recently switched to Ubuntu I'm keen to have it all working :)

Answer (score 3):

This actually started working on its own. I have no idea why, it just started working after two reboots.

Answer (score 1):

My software center link in the launcher stopped working the other day,. I searched the dash and found 'Ubuntu Software' and 'Ubuntu Software Center'. Dragged 'Ubuntu Software Center' to the launcher as a replacement and its worked since :-)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Software Center, right click, Unlock from Launcher
Click on Files then go to /usr/share/applications
Dragg 'Ubuntu Software Center' to the launcher